# How to select a value from another column based on column condition o Posgres

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgres and this is my first post here, so I would like to thank all for the help and responses.
I have searched for another post but i could not find an answer for my case.

I want the column "ocupante" to copy the value from another column, considering the value on "trimestre".

For example: if the value on "trimestre" is '22T1', I want column "ocupante" to copy the value from "202201". If the value on "trimestre" is 21T4 I want column "ocupante" to copy the value from "202104".

Before it, i had to duplicate all the rows with the generate_series and create the column "trimestre", according to each genarate_series value.

Below an exemple of the result I am looking for and what I've been trying:

| siila_id | galpão | módulo | 202104 | 202201 | id_conjunto | série | trimestre | ocupante |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10598 | G.01 | M.03 | Vox | Cal | 10598G.01M.03 | 1 | 22T1 | Cal |
| 10598 | G.01 | M.03 | Vox | Cal | 10598G.01M.03 | 2 | 21T4 | Vox |

This is the query I have been trying to run:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN trimestre = '22T1' THEN (SELECT 202201 FROM siila_01) 
         WHEN trimestre = '21T4' THEN (SELECT 202104 FROM siila_01)
    END AS ocupante
    
FROM(

SELECT *, 

    CASE WHEN série = 1 THEN '22T1'
    WHEN série = 2 THEN '21T4'
    END AS trimestre
    
FROM(
    SELECT *, CONCAT(siila_id, galpão, módulo) AS id_conjunto, generate_series(1,2) AS série
FROM siila_01) AS sub_01) 
AS sub_02 
    
;
```

At the end I get the following error:

*ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000*

In my begginner understandment is Posgres trying to fit all the "202104" values on a ROW, then it results on a error? I tried other solution but i could not find any solution yet.

I aprecciate all the help!
Thank you.

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a subquery, just select the column.

However, because the column has an awkward name it must be [quoted to make Postgres realize it is an identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) rather than a number.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN trimestre = '22T1' THEN "202201"
         WHEN trimestre = '21T4' THEN "202104"
    END AS ocupante
```

Note that you can simplify this query by only generating the series in the subquery and doing the rest in a single select.

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(siila_id, galpão, módulo) AS id_conjunto,
    CASE WHEN série = 1 THEN '22T1'
         WHEN série = 2 THEN '21T4'
    END AS trimestre,
    CASE WHEN série = 1 THEN "202201"
         WHEN série = 2 THEN "202104"
    END AS ocupante
FROM(
    SELECT *, generate_series(1,2) AS série
    FROM siila_01
) AS sub_01
```

Note that having individual columns for individual month/years is likely a poor schema design. Instead, use a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) with a row for each siila's month/year. This would likely make this subquery unnecessary.

Comment: Schwen, thank you very much for your patience e help!

It really helped me with this problem I have been working since yesterday.

Also, I copied your improvements that made the query much cleaner.

I am reading the articles and trying to understand how to improve our table.

Once again, thak you very much for the help! Even more considering it is a begginner question.

Comment: @EricPalmeira SQL is hard to wrap your head around, but 1000% worth it. If you want help improving your schema, ask another question; show your table and ask how it can be improved with join tables. Link to the question in a comment here and I'll have a look.

Comment: Great, will make it soon when the database is more consolidated. You just motivated me to keep the track. Regards from Brazil!